# how to make a array of pointer to call func pointer?

Tags: c

i have code to array of func pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int a, int b);
int subtract(int a, int b);
int mul(int a, int b);
int div(int a, int b);

int (*p[4]) (int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
  int result;
  int i, j, op;

  p[0] = sum; /* address of sum() */
  p[1] = subtract; /* address of subtract() */
  p[2] = mul; /* address of mul() */
  p[3] = div; /* address of div() */

  printf("Enter two numbers: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);

  printf("0: Add, 1: Subtract, 2: Multiply, 3: Divide\n");
  do {
    printf("Enter number of operation: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);
  } while(op<0 || op>3);

  result = (*p[op]) (i, j);
  printf("%d", result);

  return 0;
}

int sum(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int subtract(int a, int b)
{
  return a - b;
}

int mul(int a, int b)
{
  return a * b;
}

int div(int a, int b)
{
  if(b) 
      return a / b;
  else 
      return 0;
}
```

code for array of pointer to function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int, int);
int product(int, int);
int subtract(int, int);

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   int a = 10;
   int b = 5;
   int result = 0;
   int (*pfun[3])(int, int);

   pfun[0] = sum;
   pfun[1] = product;
   pfun[2] = subtract;

   for( i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
   {
     result = pfun[i](a, b);
     printf("\nresult = %d", result);
   }

   result = pfun[1](pfun[0](a, b), pfun[2](a, b));
   printf("\n\nThe product of the sum and the subtract = %d\n",result);
}

int sum(int x, int y)
{
   return x + y;
}

int product(int x, int y)
{
   return x * y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
   return x - y;
}
```

now how to combine this two program. such that array of pointers pointing to func pointers and the func pointers may have different number of args? any suggestion.

Comment: You tell me! Which language are you writing in?

Comment: Then why did you write the C++ tag?

Answer (score 4):

You not only need to store function pointers with a variable number of arguments (that is not very difficult, you could use a `union` for instance), but you also need to make sure you call the functions with the correct argument, and that is a bit trickier given your design.

I suggest to use a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) instead. All your functions would only take the stack as an argument:

```
void sum(stack_t *stack);
void subtract(stack_t *stack);
void product(stack_t *stack);
```

And your array could be declared this way:

```
typedef void callback_t(stack_t *);

callback_t *p[] =
{
    sum,
    subtract,
    product,
    /* ... */
};
```

Then for instance `sum` would be implemented as such:

```
void sum(stack_t *stack)
{
    if (depth(stack) < 2)
        perror("Not enough arguments in stack!");
    int b = popstack(stack);
    int a = popstack(stack);
    int c = a + b;
    pushstack(stack, c);
}
```

But unary minus would be implemented this way:

```
void neg(stack_t *stack)
{
    if (depth(stack) < 1)
        perror("Not enough arguments in stack!");
    int a = popstack(stack);
    pushstack(stack, -a);
}
```

Each function decides how many arguments they need. The caller does not need to know.

Comment: @thuk: I'm not sure I understand the question but I added what I think is the information you need; tell me if it's what you wanted.